# Question about proof for invariance principle problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, proof-explanation

I don't see how they got that $b-c \equiv0$ mod $(3)$ and  $a-c \equiv0$ mod $(3)$?

$\phantom{}$

[image]

**

- **Solution**

**
[image: Solution]

Comment: Do you know the definition of $b-c\equiv \bmod 3$? It means that $3\mid b-c$. Now $(b-1)-(c-1)=(b-c)$ and $b-1-(c+2)=(b-c)-3$. So these differences stay equal modulo $3$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I see that the differences stay equal but how do we know that the initial b-c is divisble by 3?

Comment: We do not know that the initial $b-c$ is divisible by $3$. As you said yourself, take $b=15$ and $c=17$. It is only claimed that $b-c\equiv 0\bmod 3$ is an invariant.

Answer (score 0):

If $$(a',b',c')= (a+2,b-1,c-1)\implies $$

$$ a'-b' = (a+2)-(b-1) = a-b +3 \equiv_3 a-b $$
and
$$a'-c' = (a+2)-(c-1) = a-c +3 \equiv_3 a-c $$
and
$$b'-c' = (b-1)-(c-1) = b-c  $$

The same holds for other two cases.

Comment: But what tells us that $3\mid b-c$?  Even in the special case he provides, where $b=15$ and $c=17$, $b-c \equiv 1$ mod $3$

Answer (score 0):

Consider for example the transformation
$$(a,b,c) \mapsto (a',b',c')=(a+2,b-1,c-1)$$
You can see here that, if you note $I(a,b,c)=a-b\mod 3$,
$$I(a',b',c')=a'-b'\mod 3 = (a+2)-(b-1)\mod 3 = a-b+3\mod 3 = a-b\mod 3 = I(a,b,c)$$
So $I$ is an invariant of the transform. You should verify that this is the case whatever triple you chose to transform $(a,b,c)$ to.